# Estimate rate of convergence for a sequence to a limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, rate-of-convergence

Suppose we have a sequence $\{x_k\} \subset X$ with $X$ being a Banach space satisfying
 $$\| x_k - x_{k-1} \| \le \frac{1}{k^2} C,$$ 
where $C$ is some positive constant. The sequence clearly has a limit since
for sufficiently large $n, m$
\begin{align*}
\|x_n - x_m\| \le \sum_{j=n}^m \|x_j - x_{j+1}\| \le \sum_{j=n}^m \frac{C}{j^2} \le \varepsilon,
\end{align*}
for every $\varepsilon > 0$.

I am wondering whether we could determine the rate of convergence for the sequence $\{ \|x_k - x\| \}$ as a function of $k$ where $x$ is the limit point? It seems triangle inequality does not give a sensible result.

Comment: I don't think so. If we work even in $\mathbb{R}$, we can make any $x_k$ be arbitrarily far away from $x$. Consider $\{x_k\}$ where if $k<L$, then $x_k=\sum_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{n}$ and if $k\geq L$, then $x_k=\sum_{n=1}^L \frac{1}{n}$. Because $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ diverges, you can make $|x_k-x|$ be as large as you want.

Comment: @Cbjork: Nice example. I should've thought about this. What about the progression replace by $1/k^2$. See my edit, thanks.

Comment: With the new upper bound $$\| x_k - x_{k-1} \| \leqslant \frac C{k^2}$$ one gets $$\| x_k - x^* \| \leqslant C\sum_{i=k+1}^\infty\frac 1{i^2}<\frac Ck$$

Comment: @Did: Got it. Thanks for your comment.